# What are the best practices in monitoring DelayedJob?

Tags: monitoring, heroku, delayed-job

What is the best way to get alerts of some kind (email, HTTP callback, etc) about failed jobs in DelayedJob?

I'm running in Heroku, so keeping the workers alive (god, monit, etc) is taken care of.

NewRelic's error tracking functionality apparently doesn't register fatal errors in `Delayed::PerformableMethod`, but I do get performance metrics about stuff that doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

I use Exceptional (http://getexceptional.com).

I had to do a little custom integration, but it was really simple.

http://pinds.com/2010/11/24/tracking-errors-in-collectiveideas-delayedjob-using-exceptional/